# Site not working through recently added domain but works as a sub-directory of original domain

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am new to Joomla and have created a website using it. For the development purpose, I created my Joomla(3) installation as a subdirectory of my existing website. Now I want to use my production domain. when I point my new URL to the existing installation, Nothing seems to work other the homepage( [-]minus Theme Images). I cannot understand what the problem is even after googling for 3 days. Please give me some pointers and ask for any information I need to provide for you to batter understand the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your website live for now? If yes, please provide the `domain name` and the `sub-directory` name.

Comment: Sure @Saibbyweb, it is working through http://clarionit.in/joomla but not through http://moveonindia.in

Comment: The most obvious place to look is the .htaccess file. Try temporarily copying the default `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual Joomla installation is present on this domain `clarionit.in` and you're trying to access it from another domain `moveonindia.in`. All your content is stored in `Jdatabase` including the relative `file paths` of your content and with every new domain you will try to reach your Joomla website, the absolutes paths of these resources will vary.

Example :

The main header image's relative path is stored in **Jdatabase** as

`/joomla/images/rajeshmunat.png`

> Which means when you try to access it via `clarionit.in` its
>   path becomes:

`http://clarionit.in`**/joomla/images/rajeshmunat.png** which is correct.

> But when you try to access it via `moveonindia.in`, it tries to get it at:

`http://moveoninida.in`**/joomla/images/rajeshmunat.png**

**which is incorrect** and that's why you don't see all your images via the second domain. So you basically need to manually change the source urls of these images from your Joomla Admin panel.

Or

Instead of redirecting the other domain, point the second domain to your Joomla webhost's name servers. After that move all the contents of your `Joomla folder` to the `root folder` except the `images folder` and you are good go.